# Create a SparseMatrix using la4j java library

Tags: java, matrix, sparse-matrix, storing-data

In the package

```
org.la4j.matrix.SparseMatrix
```

there are some constructors useful to create a new SparseMatrix, they are also in the documentation http://la4j.org/apidocs/org/la4j/matrix/SparseMatrix.html#SparseMatrix-int-int-

But if I try to use the constructor like this

```
SparseMatrix A = new SparseMatrix(1000, 1000);
```

Eclipse says

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Cannot instantiate the type SparseMatrix
```

Thus I've tried to use

```
SparseMatrix G = SparseMatrix.zero(4, 4);
G.set(0,2, 3.4);
```

but it creates a large matrix of zero.

```
0,000 0,000 3,400 0,000
0,000 0,000 0,000 0,000
0,000 0,000 0,000 0,000
0,000 0,000 0,000 0,000
```

Why doesn't it store only the nonzero values? Why does compiler fail using SparseMatrix constructor?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`SparseMatrix` is [an abstract class](https://github.com/vkostyukov/la4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/la4j/matrix/SparseMatrix.java#L43) in la4j. You can create an instance of the sparse matrix using the constructors of concrete instances: [`CRSMatrix`](http://la4j.org/apidocs/org/la4j/matrix/sparse/CRSMatrix.html) or [`CCSMatrix`](http://la4j.org/apidocs/org/la4j/matrix/sparse/CCSMatrix.html).

I don't really understand the question about `zero` method. But according the docs it does exactly what you're saying - creating a zero matrix (matrix with all zeros). I would recommend to use the `zero` method instead of calling constructors.

```
SparseMatrix a = CRSMatrix.zero(1000, 1000); // 1000x1000 matrix
```